# password security hashing again and again or just a single time

Tags: php, security, passwords, password-encryption

Is it more secure to store a password with:

```
$password=hash(sha512, $_POST['password']);
$password=hash(sha512, $password);
$password=hash(sha256, $password);
$password=md5('JIOA#324FKJ///#dfr3inj1HJ4_jbbf-vbd31ds4_-_nURl//\&dffve@.add123456789fs-@drgko489d', $password);
$password=hash(sha512, $password);
```

Would all this be safer than just:

```
$password=hash(sha512, $_POST['password']);
```

Comment: Look at this: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/115406/is-it-more-secure-to-hash-a-password-multiple-times

Comment: You should be using a salt with your hashes instead of just a raw hash.

Comment: That fourth step seems like a particularly bad idea, because md5 is insecure. The only real reason to repeat hashing is to slow things down, so that a brute force attack takes longer. And for that you need to repeat a fast hash like sha256 thousands of times.

Comment: `$password=md5('JIOA#324FKJ///#dfr3inj1HJ4_jbbf-vbd31ds4_-_nURl//\&dffve@.add123456789fs-@drgko489d', $password);`isnt this a salt?

Comment: Don't engineer your own solution. Use bcrypt. PHP 5.5 even makes this the default in the new `password_hash` built-in function. http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Comment: @user3524823 According to the PHP documentation of `md5` the second argument is a boolean that determines whether `md5` returns raw output. So basically, all previous steps are cast out and you get the same result at the end of the line every time.

Comment: But my question was is the first one safer than the second one? EDIT: And is it safe?

Comment: @user3524823 it is very much _less_ safe; and indeed quite unsafe.

Comment: @towr So if I just do `$password=brcrypt($_POST['password'];`it would be safe?

Comment: @user3524823 If you have php 5.5+ you can use [password_hash](http://php.net/password_hash); for php 5.3/5.4 you can use [crypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php), but you have to be careful not to use the default settings (so read the documentation).

Answer (score 1):

No, because - as towr has pointed out - the first one returns the same `$password` **every time** which is clearly not what you intended. The second one is for practical intends as bad as saving the password in cleartext. There huge databases online that where you can look up the passwords for a specific hash. If we look at what the first code intended to do (and I guess the md5 step was meant to concatenate the two strings) then that is better, because it uses the string in the md5 step as salt. The salt is static though, so it is still a really bad password hashing scheme overall. You might want to read up on some [password hashing basics](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/09/about-secure-password-hashing/).

In any case I would advice you to follow ceejayoz' suggestion and use the `password_hash` function of PHP 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

None of the suggested hashing schemes are appropriate for hashing passwords, because they are all ways too fast. You need a slow key-derivation function like BCrypt or PBKDF2, with an adaptable cost factor.

PHP offers the new function [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to calculate BCrypt hashes. It simplifies all the tricky things like generating a safe salt. For earlier PHP versions you can use the [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php).

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```